# '$' is undefined

Tags: jquery, spbodyonload

I am getting the message '$' is undefined below is my code 
these are the script tags i am using

```
  script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js" /script
script type="text/javascript"

$(document).ready(function () {
    // Wait until SP.JS has loaded before calling getWebUserData 
    ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(getWebUserData, "sp.js");
});

var context = null; 
var web = null; 
var currentUser = null;
var userGroups = null;
var displayGroups = null;

function getWebUserData() {

    context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();   // Get the current user 
    web = context.get_web();                        // Get the current web    
    currentUser = web.get_currentUser();            // Get the current user 
    context.load(currentUser);                      // Load the current user 

    context.executeQueryAsync(onSuccessMethod, onFailureMethod);
}

function onSuccessMethod() {

    alert('User name:' + currentUser.get_title() + '\n Login Name:' + currentUser.get_loginName());

}

function onFailureMethod(sender, args) {

    alert('request failed ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());

}
/script
```

Comment: I assume you are just missing the < > around the script tags? A cut and paste error? Also I recommend using a protocol agnostic src="//ajax..."

Answer (score 2):

`'$' is undefined` is mean the **jquery is not loaded**, so try to make sure the code format like the following (I tried this on my side in script editor that have worked properly)

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function () {
    // Wait until SP.JS has loaded before calling getWebUserData 
    ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(getWebUserData, "sp.js");
});

var context = null; 
var web = null; 
var currentUser = null;
var userGroups = null;
var displayGroups = null;

function getWebUserData() {

    context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();   // Get the current user 
    web = context.get_web();                        // Get the current web    
    currentUser = web.get_currentUser();            // Get the current user 
    context.load(currentUser);                      // Load the current user 

    context.executeQueryAsync(onSuccessMethod, onFailureMethod);
}

function onSuccessMethod() {

    alert('User name:' + currentUser.get_title() + '\n Login Name:' + currentUser.get_loginName());

}

function onFailureMethod(sender, args) {

    alert('request failed ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());

}
</script>
```